# Pip gets removed from virtual env after install a package

Tags: python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

I have created a virtual environment:

```
Python -m venv test
```

I then checked that pip was indeed in the environment. this is the content of the scripts folder:

```
activate      deactivate.bat         pip.exe*     python.exe*
activate.bat  easy_install.exe*      pip3.9.exe*  pythonw.exe*

Activate.ps1  easy_install-3.9.exe*  pip3.exe*
```

I then ran which pip to confirm that it would be the env pip, which it was.

I wanted to install django:

```
pip install django
```

After i installed it, i ran which pip again, but this time it was pointing to system pip. The scripts folder in my environment no longer had the pip files.

How do i keep things  separate?